# problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i have sorted xml file on the basis of item no.now  i am trying to display data  in javascript, but my code doesn't work, can anybody tell me what is wrong here

item.php:

```
         $xmlFile = "items.xml";
         $doc= DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
         $item = $doc->getElementsByTagName("item"); 
         $items=array(); 
         foreach($item as $node) 
           {   
        $itemno = $node->getElementsByTagName("itemno");
        $itemno = $itemno->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $quantity = $node->getElementsByTagName("quantity");
        $quantity = $quantity->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $available = $node->getElementsByTagName("available");
        $available = $available->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $items[$itemno]= array($itemno,$quantity,$available);
           }

        ksort($items, SORT_NUMERIC); 
        foreach($item AS $ite => $no) 
         { 
           $itemnum=$no[0];
           $qty=$no[1];
           $avail=$no[2];
           echo $itemnum;  
           echo $qty;                 
           echo $avail;
         }
```

js:

```
var xhr = createRequest();
function getit( ) {
xhr.open("GET", 'item.php', true); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = getConfirm;  
xhr.send(null); 
}



function getConfirm()
{
if ((xhr.readyState == 4) &&(xhr.status == 200))   
   {
      var data = xhr.responseText;
      alert(data);                  
   }
}
```

Comment: I have retagged it to javascript, as it is related to it not to Java.

Answer (score 1):

try xmlrequest in this flow in your javascript:

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
    else
     {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
     {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
                document.getElementById("tbRow").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                //lo();
         }
     }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","tbrow.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Here "tbRow" is a "div" id. i.e.,

```
 <div id="tbRow"></div>
```

Comment: but my code doesnt have any div tag, i want to display the php echo data through alert(); in javascript.

Comment: just create an empty div tag to store returned values.Then you can later use to show in alert box